# UISwipeGestureRecognizer Custom Action with UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add a swipe gesture (left/right) in order to hide/show my side menu.
I got it working perfectly on a UIView, however, I'm having trouble with an UITableView.

Here's my code to add my swipe gestures to my TableView:

```
// Add right swipe gesture recognizer

    let rightSwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "toggleSideMenu")
    rightSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction =  UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    self.timelineTableView.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipeGestureRecognizer)

    // Add left swipe gesture recognizer
    let leftSwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "toggleSideMenu")
    leftSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    //sideMenuContainerView.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipeGestureRecognizer)
    self.timelineTableView.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipeGestureRecognizer)
```

Here's my selector method :

```
func toggleSideMenu() {
    println("ENTER SWIPE")
    toggleSideMenuView()
}
```

I've also done this :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

However, my selector menu "toggleSideMenu()" is never called when I swipe left or right.

P.S: I've also tried to add those swipe gesture on my UITableViewCell directly but it doesn't work as well.

Anyone has an idea? Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: rightSwipeGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;

Comment: In my project this function is called with this code..

Comment: Did your tableview implement swipe to delete?

Comment: Thanks Kirit Modi ! I had to add the delegate method shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer to return true to make this work as well !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to Kirit Modi. Here's the **solution to my problem**:

Add :

```
leftSwipeGestureRecognizer.delegate = self    
rightSwipeGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
```

Then add the **UIGestureRecognizerDelegate** delegate method :

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me helped

```
(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
return YES;
}
```

because i had two gestures. One from slide menu and one from current VC. So that one from slide menu killed VC's gestures.